# How to find like integers in multiple list

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, linq

In a vb.net application I have a set of integers currently stored in multiple Arraylist (But this could be something different if required)

al1 = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9}
al2 = {2, 3, 4, 9}
al3 = {2, 3, 19}

I would like to get the set {2, 3}

I thought about using LINQ to join the list, but the number of Arraylist can change. Im open to any ideas. I know I can always loop through everything and check if an integer exsist and keep track of it, but I thought there might be an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Enumerable.Intersect` method for this. And change your `ArrayList` to a `List(Of T)`. That makes it easier to use LINQ methods.

```
Dim set = al1.Intersect(al2).Intersect(al3)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Steven's answer: if you can't change your `ArrayList` objects to `List(Of Integer)` objects, you can still do this:

```
Dim set = al1.OfType(Of Integer)() _
    .Intersect(al2.OfType(Of Integer)()) _
    .Intersect(al3.OfType(Of Integer)())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have code that gives the common items of two lists, it's easy to extend that into any number of lists:

- Get a list of common items of the first two lists.
- Then get the common items of this result list and the third source list,
- Then the common items of the new result list and the fourth source list
- etc.

Comment: Hee Hans. 't Wordt tijd dat je LINQ gaat leren, je antwoord is veel te generiek ;-) Trouwens, ik miste jullie dit jaar op de DevDays.

Comment: Hoi Steven, ik had het expres generiek gehouden, het klonk nogal als huiswerk. En inderdaad, we waren er niet. Volgende keer beter.